# Using trapz to find the area under a curve

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am attempting to use [trapz](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html?searchHighlight=trapz&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to find the area under the curve.

My `x` data represents datetime, and my `y` data represents acceleration as a `f(x)`. Accelerometer readings are in the form of SI.

Example data within x ( HH:mm:ss.SSS ) :

```
'01:06:48.330'
'01:06:48.352'
'01:06:48.374'
```

Example data within y ( accelerometer value * 9.81 ):

```
8.73750256159470
8.59619296907904
8.63520263017352
```

When I enter the following command (using the whole array of data ):

```
velocity = trapz(x,y);
```

I get back a duration array which looks like this:

```
velocity = 
    duration
    00:00:13
```

I am not entirely too sure I understand what 00:00:13 means. When I calculate for velocity, I'd expect to see something like 9.81 m/s , or 5m/s. Am I misusing the function or should I convert the duration array to a different object type?

Comment: MATLAB has no "awareness" that your y axis is an acceleration, just that you have something of units datetime multiplied by scalars during the `trapz` calculation... Without some example for us to reproduce, it's hard to tell you how 13 seconds relates to your expected result.

Comment: @Wolfie gotcha. sure thing, I updated the question with a small example. Then it might be 9.81 * 13 sec to get the actual velocity?

Comment: Note that a better example would have 2 traits: **1.** It actually gives the result you've also quoted (using those three values does not yield 13secs). **2.** we can actually copy and paste the code to run and adapt it. Something like `x=datetime({'00:00','00:01','00:02'},'inputformat','HH:mm'); y=[1,2,4];` with the resulting `trapz` duration being 4mins 30secs. Creating simple examples like this can also help you help yourself, as it improves understanding about what's going on with simple numbers you could do hand calculations with.

Comment: @Wolfie I agree. I usually do a  better job when i know what the issue is. This was just a curve ball for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you expect `m/s` output from integrating acceleration is simply because you're doing a particular calculation involving `(m/s^2)*s`, i.e. y axis * x axis.

Let's use a simple example, where we first convert to seconds and then integrate.

```
x = datetime( {'00:00', '00:01', '00:02'}, 'inputformat', 'HH:mm' ); % Time
y = [1 2 4]; % Acceleration (m/s^2)

x_elapsed_seconds = datenum(x-min(x))*24*60*60; % Datenum returns days, convert to secs

z = trapz( x_elapsed_seconds, y ); % Velocity = 270 m/s
```

We can verify that, for this example, 270m/s is correct because there are simply 2 trapeziums in the calculation:

1. Trapezium from `1m/s^2` to `2m/s^2` lasting 1min = 60secs: `60*(1+2)/2 = 60*1.5 = 90 m/s`
2. Trapezium from `2m/s^2` to `4m/s^2` lasting 1min = 60secs: `60*(2+4)/2 = 60*3 = 180 m/s`

We sum the trapezium areas for the result: `90 + 180 = 270` as expected. This is why it's always best to use a simple example for verification before using real world data.

Comment: to me, it would make sense to use the “speed” formula, to calculate traveled distance from start to finish given the velocity ( integral of acceleration ) . would that make sense to you?

Comment: I have no idea what speed formula you're referring to... by integrating acceleration against time, you are basically doing `v = u + at`, assuming your initial speed `u` is 0, and `a` is not constant so you require an integral. Use other [SUVAT equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line) for distance etc

Comment: speed formula : speed = distance / time. so using that formula, speed is the abs(velocity), and time is the elapsed time. so one could solve for distance, no?

Comment: That formula only works if your speed is constant, which it is not or you wouldn't need to integrate the (variable) acceleration to approximate it. You need another integral.Referring to my previous link, you want `s = ut + 0.5*at^2` integrating w.r.t `t` in place of multiplication because `a` is not constant. Or approximate the speed at many places in a loop and estimate distance that way.

Answer (score 1):

Datetimes are usually tricky in MATLAB. I would convert it to seconds before doing any integrals. Here is an example solution.

```
x=['01:06:48.330'; '01:06:48.352'; '01:06:48.374'];
datetime(x,'Format','HH:mm:ss.SSS');
secvec = datevec(x);
secvec = 3600*secvec(:,4)+60*secvec(:,5)+secvec(:,6); % times measured in seconds

y = [8.73750256159470; 8.59619296907904; 8.63520263017352]; % accelerations in m/s^2
trapz(secvec,y)
>> ans = 0.380216002428058 % Gained velocity, measured in m/s
```