# Finding the area within a hysteresis loop

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I need to find the area within this hysteresis loop and this is the code that i have
[hysteresis loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2iq8.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXWT8.png)

I tried googling some things but i dont understand how to use them.

Comment: hi, perhaps use `trapz` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403203/using-trapz-to-find-the-area-under-a-curve

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the question is I have an excel file with all the data and there are so many values of B and H that i dont know how to use trapz